# Angular.js: hide a div from my index file when viewing any one of multiple partials

Tags: angularjs, scope, routes, location, partials

I'm hoping that this question isn't going to get me punched in the head but as I'm *this* (holds fingers closely together) far from punching myself in the head I figured I'd go ahead, swallow my pride and ask anyway.

As a self confessed Angular newbie I'm having an issue hiding a div on my index file (which is my layout page) when a visitor calls specific partials to that page.

I have around 55 partials  (scope creep is a wonderful thing) and the offending div should not appear on 12 of them.

Here is my markup:

```
<div ng-show="somename" id="somename" ng-controller="somenameCtrl">
                        <div ng-include="'templates/somename.html'"></div>
                    </div>
```

and here is my controller:

```
app.controller('somenameCtrl', function($scope, $route, $location) {

   $scope.$on('$routeChangeSuccess', function() {
      var path = $location.path();
      console.log(path);
      $scope.somename = true;
      if (path === '/thatpage') {
         $scope.somename = true;
      } else if (path === '/thispage') {
         $scope.somename = false;
   }
 });
});
```

I figured that this would be the simplest way forward, but now I'm less convinced as (as previously stated) I have several partials to hide the div from the index file. Obviously the div is not showing on 'thispage', and is showing correctly on 'thatpage' (and where any partial other than 'thispage' is called.

However, I need to not show the div on pages 'thispage2' -> 'thispage12' and keep it shown on everything else. Any idea on how I can achieve this?

Any help would be gratefully appreciated - if there's anything unclear, please do let me know and I'll try my best to give greater clarity.

Comment: What form of routing are you using? ngRoute or uiRouter?

Answer (score 2):

There are many ways of doing this in Angular. Too many.

I'm assuming you use ui-router or ng-router. Both routers have a `resolve` method in them. In each route/state you define, you can pass in the `SomeName` variable like so:

```
.when('/someRoute', {
    templateUrl: '...',
    controller: '...',
    resolve: {
      SomeName: false;
    }
  })
```

And then include this in your controller:

```
.controller(function(SomeName, $scope) {
    $scope.somename = SomeName || false;
}
```

This way, you need to define the `SomeName` variable **only in the routes where it's true**. It would default to false when not defined, so you won't need to define it on every route

Of course, there are other methods of doing this as well, but this seems to me like the cleanest method

Comment: Thank you very much @nikjohn - I'll have a crack at this now. You're quite correct, I'm using ngRoute.